# NextJS and next-routes not routing as I would expect

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I've created a routes.js file that is as follows:

```
const nextRoutes = require('next-routes');
const routes = module.exports = nextRoutes();

routes.add
    ('presenterallcurrent', '/presenter/:ccyear','speaker');
routes.add
    ('speakersessiondetail', '/presenter/:ccyear/:slugSpeaker','speakerdetail');
```

I am expecting that when I browse to:

```
/presenter/2018/douglas-crockford-1124
```

I will be taken to my /pages/speakerdetail.js file with query.ccyear and query.slugSpeaker populated to 2018 and douglas-crockford-1124

I am expecting that when I browse to

```
/presenter/2018
```

I will be taken to /pages/speaker.js with query.ccyear set to 2018

The second case works as I expect (/presenter/2018) does take me to /pages/speaker.js, but (/presenter/2018/douglas-crockford-1124 gives me a 404.

What am I not understanding and why does this not work?

In my /pages/speaker and /pages/speakerdetail:

```
    static async getInitialProps({query}) {...}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's a 404 from not resolving to `/pages/speakerdetail.js`, or is there something happening in the `getInitialProps` of that page that is causing a 404?

Comment: I have a console.log at top of getinitialprops not being hit.

Comment: The filename has that exact capitalization?

Comment: I did solve this. I had the basics, just some syntax issues.  example here https://github.com/pkellner/next-routes-problem

Answer (score 0):

For optional parameters in your route, add a trailing `?` and adjust `speaker.js` to render either the year view or detail view based on whether the `query.slugSpeaker` is undefined.

```
routes.add
    ('speaker', '/presenter/:ccyear/:slugSpeaker?');
```